# React app throws TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name') when compiling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

I keep running into an issue with my CRUD application when I go to edit a name from my list, it throws an error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')".

It seems to stem from the "value={selectedUser.name}" in my input field, but when I remove it the app compiles but I cannot alter the field at all - nothing happens when you type. Any help is appreciated!

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from 'react'
import { GlobalContext } from '../context/GlobalState'
import { Link, useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, Button } from 'reactstrap'

const EditUser = (props) => {
const [selectedUser, setSelectedUser] = useState({
  id: '',
  name: ''
});
const { users, editUser } = useContext(GlobalContext);
const navigate = useNavigate();
const currentUserId = useParams(props);

useEffect(() => {
  const userId = currentUserId;
  const selectedUser = users.find(user => user.id === userId)
  setSelectedUser(selectedUser)
}, [currentUserId, users])

const onSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  editUser(selectedUser)
  navigate('/');
}

const onChange = (e) => {
  setSelectedUser({...selectedUser, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
}

  return (
    <div>
        <Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            <FormGroup>
                <Label>Edit Name</Label>
                <Input type='text' name='name' value={selectedUser.name} onChange={onChange} placeholder='Enter Name'></Input>
            </FormGroup>
        <Button type='submit'>Edit Name</Button>
        <Link to='/' className='btn btn-danger m-2'>Back</Link>
        </Form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default EditUser
```

Comment: `value={selectedUser?.name}`. Does this fix your problem ?

Comment: No :( 

Failed to compile
./src/components/EditUser.js 78:24
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (78:24)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|     type: "text",
|     name: "name",
>     value: selectedUser?.name,
|     onChange: onChange,
|     placeholder: "Enter Name",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `currentUserId` is `undefined` for any reason, or your `users.find()` returns `undefined`, then you're going to be storing `undefined` in your `selectedUser` state variable.

Given from your comments it looks like you're not able to use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (the `foo?.bar` syntax) then you probably just want to prevent this at source:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const userId = currentUserId;
    const foundUser = users.find((user) => user.id === userId);
    if (foundUser) {
      setSelectedUser(foundUser);
    } 
  }, [currentUserId, users]);
```

Also note I renamed your variable inside your `useEffect` to avoid confusion with your `selectedUser` at the higher level.

Comment: Thanks Millhouse! That cleared the error out but it doesn't update the name when I click 'Edit Name' now.

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

`Array.prototype.find` returns the first matching element, or ***undefined*** if no such match is found.

```
const selectedUser = users.find(user => user.id === userId); // potentially undefined
```

Additionally, the returned value from the `useParams` hook is an object of the key-value pairs of any defined route path parameters. The code appears to incorrectly assume the returned value ***is*** the `currentUserId` parameter from a path, and uses that to search the `users` array.

```
const currentUserId = useParams(props);

useEffect(() => {
  const userId = currentUserId;
  const selectedUser = users.find(user => user.id === userId);
  setSelectedUser(selectedUser);
}, [currentUserId, users]);
```

I doubt there could *ever* be a found match comparing `user.id` against the returned params object.

## Solution

I suspect that the *actual* path param is really `userId`. Either destructure it immediately from the `useParams` hook.

```
const { userId } = useParams();
```

or rename `currentUserId` to `params` and destructure `userId` in the hook.

```
const params = useParams(props);

useEffect(() => {
  const { userId } = params;
  const selectedUser = users.find(user => user.id === userId);
  setSelectedUser(selectedUser);
}, [params.userId, users]);
```

One last point about route params and id properties. The route params will ***always*** be a string type. Sometimes the `id` is actually a number type, so you'll want to use a type-safe equality check. Convert ids to string types, which covers both string ids and will convert numbers to number-like strings.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const { userId } = params;
  const selectedUser = users.find(user => String(user.id) === userId);
  setSelectedUser(selectedUser);
}, [params.userId, users]);
```

Guarding against null/undefined values.

1. First, try to maintain a stable `selectedUser` state invariant. In other words, don't update it an undefined value unless you have a specific need to. Check the result of `users.find` to see if a match was found.

   ```
   const { userId } = useParams(props);

   useEffect(() => {
     const selectedUser = users.find(user => String(user.id) === userId);
     if (selectedUser) {
       setSelectedUser(selectedUser);
     }
   }, [userId, users]);
   ```
2. Second, defensively guard against potentially null/undefined accesses in your render function, just in case. You can use the Optional Chaining and Nullish Coalescing Operators to guard null access and provide a valid defined value for the controlled input.

   ```
   <Input
     type='text'
     name='name'
     value={selectedUser?.name ?? ""}
     onChange={onChange}
     placeholder='Enter Name'
   />
   ```

   or if you prefer older-school null-checks/guard-clauses

   ```
   <Input
     type='text'
     name='name'
     value={(selectedUser && selectedUser.name) ?? ""}
     onChange={onChange}
     placeholder='Enter Name'
   />
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation, Drew, that helped clarify things. I am still having an issue with not being able to edit even after trying your suggestions, however. When I click on edit it lets me type a new name, but when I submit nothing changes. Maybe somewhere else in my code something is wrong? I am stumped. :(

Comment: @DavidFeudale To clarify, are you saying the specific issue regarding the `.name` property is resolved, but you now have another issue with submitting the form? If so then this seems unrelated to the post, off-topic. I am more than happy to dig deeper, but this should be done through a new post that is specific to the issue of the submit handler logic. If you make a new post please feel free to ping me here with a link to it and I can take a look. At a minimum, it'll likely get more eyes on *that* question faster than it would here in comments.